# Get photos from google maps by coordinates

Tags: google-maps, photos

I'm trying to get photos from google maps on the square 2x2km. Does anybody know how can I get them?

Answer (score 0):

[Google static maps api](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) is what you need